# How to prevent converge to mean solution for regression problems in CNN?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, torch

I am training a CNN for predicting joints on hands. The problem is that my net always converges to the mean value of the training set, and I can only get identical results for different test images. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm dealing with a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be using the `MSECriterion()`? It is the standard *l2* (minimum square error) loss. While the CNN tries to predict results, there are multiple modes through which the result can be correct. And what *l2* loss does is that it converges to an average of all these modes as that is the most feasible way it can intuitively approach to attain less-penalized results.

> The MSE-based solution
>   appears overly smooth due to the pixel-wise average of
>   possible solutions in the pixel space

To pick the optimum mode of answer, you can look into `adversarial loss` [LINK](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiE56G2oqzTAhVLrY8KHeB8DuIQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1406.2661&usg=AFQjCNEYi3th_8xRH0BIjxxmc-AM4lKdzA&sig2=XzUiulxFYpqgyRHFKQ3N1A). This loss picks the optimum mode based on what it thinks is realistic in terms of the data it has seen.

For further clarification, look at figure 3 in this paper: [SRGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04802.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I was using `tensorflow`. Was trying to do some `regression` using simple CNN with one neuron in output layer. Was optimizing mean square error:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_prediction - y_output_placeholder))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)
```

My problem was I made output placeholder of true values with different shape than output predictions of the net.

- placeholder's shape was [None]
- predictions's shape was [None, 1].

When I changed placeholder's shape to match the one of prediction output problem was solved.